# Why does Eclipse run the JSP despite having an error?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse lists the following error:
`The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path`
for a file called `TestClient.jsp`.
When I run it on the Tomcat server. It still runs and my webservice returns everything correctly.

Why the error?
Note: Tomcat has already been added to build path and the facets both.

Comment: Do you build with eclipse and deploy this then to the server? I ask because these days, people usually use a separate build tool to build. The build path of eclipse and the build tool can be different

Comment: No it's just plain old Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of Eclipse that lets your project target Tomcat 10, but doesn't yet have support for the new default superclass for JSPs that's part of the new Jakarta EE packages, so probably 2020-12. 2021-03 has a fix for that, so please update.

Comment: Actually I'm already using 2021-03. I installed eclipse today only, it's the latest version it gave me.

Comment: That's odd, then. Your project is actually compiling against Tomcat 10, and you've cleaned and rebuilt at some point?

Comment: It's a Dynamic Web Project? What happens if you right-click on the file and manually revalidate it (using "Validate")?